# Download songs from iTunes to iPhone

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, iphone

When trying to download songs from iTunes to my iPhone, a message pops up saying I have to delete and sync. Will this delete all my photos, contacts, and apps from my phone? Or just the music part of my iPhone?

Comment: More detail please.  What do you do to cause this message to appear?  Are you using iTunes on the computer or the iPhone?

Comment: I am using iTunes on the computer. and what I am doing is I click the sync music button on iTunes and the message appears saying to delete and sync in order to get the music onto my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the iTunes preferences then the devices tab and tick the box about automatic syncing.

Comment: How does this prevent the "Delete and sync" warning from appearing?